# Center figures in sub figures

Tags: floats, tkz-euclide

[image]can anybody help me centre this diagram the code works in figures but not subfigures.

```
\documentclass[
 12pt,                  %Font size
 a4paper,               %Paper size
 twoside,               %Two-sided document
openright,              %Chapters start on odd pages
fleqn,                  %Left-align displayed equations
leqno,                  %Place equation numbers on the left
]{book}  
\usepackage{mathrsfs}           
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}    

\makeatletter%%%%%%centers figures
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering
\makeatother



\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
            \tkzDefPoint(1.5,0){B}
            \tkzDrawCircle[blue](A,B)
            \tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
            \tkzLabelPoints(A,B)
            \tkzDrawSegment[red](A,B)
    \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
 \end{subfigure}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
            \tkzDefPoint(1.5,0){B}
            \tkzDrawCircle[green](B,A)
            \tkzInterCC(A,B)(B,A)       \tkzGetPoints{C}{D}
            \tkzCompass[color=blue, thick](A,C)
            \tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
            \tkzLabelPoints(A,B)
            \tkzDrawSegment[red](A,B)
    \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
 \end{subfigure}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
            \tkzDefPoint(1.5,0){B}
        \tkzInterCC(A,B)(B,A)       \tkzGetPoints{C}{D}
        \tkzCompass[color=blue, thick](A,C)
        \tkzCompass[color=green, thick](B,C)
        \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
            \tkzLabelPoints(A,B)
            \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
            \tkzDrawSegments[red](A,B A,C B,C)
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
 \end{subfigure}
 \caption{}
 \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth} \centering \begin{tikzpicture} ....`

Comment: Older versions of Euclide add extra white space.  You can check this with `\draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);` at the end of each tikzpicture.

Comment: Thanks I have updated the pic

Comment: I tried \makeatletter
\newenvironment{centeredsubfigure}{%
  \par\addvspace{\abovecaptionskip}%
  \centering
}{%
  \par\addvspace{\belowcaptionskip}%
}
\makeatother
but it just won't compile